# Store results of expensive function calls in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, function, optimization

Let's suppose I have a set of integers of a variable length. I apply a function on this set of integers and I obtain a result.

`myFunction(setOfIntegers) => myResult`

Let's suppose a call to `myFunction` is very expensive and I would like to somehow store the results of this function calls.

In my application I am already using MySQL and what I was thinking was to somehow create a table with the `setOfIntegers` as a PK and `myResult` as an additional field.

I was thinking that I could do this by transforming the `setOfIntegers` to a string before storing it in the DB.

Can this be done in any other way? Or would there be a better way to store results of such function calls in order to avoid calling them a 2nd time with the same set of integers?

Comment: a primary key can cover multiple columns so there's no need to stringify it. Otherwise sounds ok. How many numbers in the set? Is that fixed?

Comment: @danblack the problem is that my ```setOfIntegers``` can have a variable length, so I cannot know in advance how many columns my table needs to have...

Comment: Is there an upper length? Is the integer range constrained?

Comment: @danblack no, there is no upper length...

Comment: Try to wrap them them in a hash function. Use a (groupnumber, int) table to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Java, but Perl has `my $str = join(',', $array)` and PHP has `$str = implode(',', $array)`.  Then the string `$str` could be used as the `PRIMARY KEY` (assuming it is not too long).  And the result would go in the other column.

Your app code (in Java) would need to first do an `implode` and `SELECT` to see if the function has already been evaluated for the given array.  If not, then perform the function and end by `INSERTing` a new row.

If this will be multi-threaded, you could use `INSERT IGNORE` to deal with dups.  (There are other solutions, too.)

Another note:  If your set-of-integers is ordered, then what I describe is 'complete'.  If it is unordered, then sort it before imploding.  This will provide a canonical representation.

Answer (score 0):

If the function can be implemented in MySQL directly, I would suggest using Views.

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx/

Comment: My function is a Java function, and I would like to store the parameter used to call that function (the ```setOfIntegers```) and it's result (the ```myResult```), so I cannot implement a view nor a stored procedure.

Comment: @MarcuDaniel - It is not (currently) possible to provide any kind of array or table as input to a View.  A Stored Procedure could be given a table of the set-of-integers, but that is quite clumsy.